# show loading image while reload page when change quantity in shoping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload a page when a change on quantity number occures and show a loading image while reloading the page.

```
var purchased = new Array();
var totalprice = 0;
function findpos(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < purchased.length; i++) {
        if (purchased[i].id == id)
            return i;
    }
    return false;
}
function change(id) {
    var i = findpos(id);
    var quan = parseInt($('#quantity' + id + '').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addcart.php",
        data: {quan: quan, id: id},
    });
    totalprice += (parseInt($('#quantity' + id + '').val()) - purchased[i].cnt) * purchased[i].price;
    $('#subTotal' + id + '').val(parseInt($('#quantity' + id + '').val()) * (purchased[i].price));
    purchased[i].cnt = parseInt($('#quantity' + id + '').val());
    $('#cartProgressPanel').show();

    update_total();
}
function update_total() {
    if (totalprice) {
        $('#total').html('مجموع:' + totalprice + 'تومان ');
        $('#total_h').val(totalprice);
        $(window).load(function () {

            $('#cartProgressPanel').hide();
        });
    }
}
```

This code is reloading the page but reload take a long time. How to reload the page faster?

Comment: Use gif image show it before ajax call hide after responce

Comment: I do but still take a long time